# Understanding Celluloid Pool

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I guess my understanding toward Celluloid Pool is sort of broken. I will try to explain below  but before that a quick note.

**Note**: Our system is running against a very `fast client` passing messages over ZeroMQ.

With the following Vanilla Celluloid app

> ```
> class VanillaClient
>    include Celluloid::ZMQ
>
>    def read
>       loop { async.evaluate_response(socket.read_multipart)
>    end
>
>    def evaluate_response(data)
>       ## the reason for using defer can be found over here.
>
>       Celluloid.defer do 
>         ExternalService.execute(data)
>       end
>    end
> end
> ```

Our system result in failure after some time, reason  `'Can't spawn more thread'` (or something like it)

So we intended to use Celluloid Pool(to avoid the above-mentioned problem ) so that we can limit the number of threads that spawned

My Understanding toward Celluloid Pool is 
Celluloid Pool maintains a pool of actors for you so that you can distribute your task in parallel.

Hence, I decide to test it, but according to my test cases, it seems to behave serially(i.e thing never get distribute or happen in parallel.)

Example to replicate this.

[`sender-1.rb`](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/c2dc7a95d4ad57fefa7e)

```
## Send message `1` to the the_client.rb
```

[`sender-2.rb`](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/a75fe123bd006e085984)

```
## Send message `2` to the the_client.rb
```

[`the_client.rb`](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/e9aa91e40fee7a6bbd08)

```
## take message from sender-1 and sender-2 and return it back to receiver.rb
## heads on, the `sleep` is introduced to test/replicate the IO block that happens in the actual code.
```

[`receiver.rb`](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/f8b67b562bb03c1128ed)

```
## print the message obtained from the_client.rb
```

If, the `sender-2.rb` is run before `sender-1.rb` it appears that the pool gets blocked for `20` sec (sleep time in `the_client.rb`,can be seen over [here](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/e9aa91e40fee7a6bbd08#file-the_client-rb-L21)) before consuming the data sent by `sender-1.rb`

It behaves the same in ruby-2.2.2 and under jRuby-9.0.5.0. What could be the possible causes for Pool to act in such manner?

Comment: @digitalextremist Your thought?

Answer (score 0):

## Your `pool` call is not asynchronous.

Execution of `evaluate` on `@pool` needs to be `.async` still, as in your original example, not using pools. You still want asynchronous behavior, but you als want to have multiple handler actors.

---

### Next you will likely hit the `Pool.async` bug.

- https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-pool/issues/6

This means after `5` hits to `evaluate` your pool will become unresponsive until at least one actor in the pool is finished. Worst case scenario, if you get `6+` requests in rapid succession, the `6th` will then take `120` seconds, because it will take `5*20` seconds before it executes, then `20` seconds to execute itself.

---

Depending on what your actual operation is that's causing you delays -- you might need to adjust your pool size down the line.